# Unable to Create Credit Memo

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-community, creditmemo, currency-rates

I am using multi-currency on magento site. Base currency of site is Danish Krone. I have placed an order with Euro and created invoice from admin for the order but when I am creating Credit memo for the order then getting error message "Maximum amount available to refund is DKK497,00".

I am getting this issue because .02 have added in subtotals as my you can see in attached screenshot. Can any one help me to resolve the issue.

[image: Credit_memo]